# Delete Droid thumbnails

Tags: android, camera, android-gallery

In my application, I use a `GalleryView` to display thumbnails. I also have some code to delete a photo. However when I refresh the `GalleryView`, the thumbnail for the deleted photo is still there. Aside from refreshing the sd card, its there a easy way to delete the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

show code for the delete - Gallery tries to pick up pictures so unless the delete is working correctly that may be where the failed-delete is

Comment: The delete absolutely is working.  I can go to the gallery and the original image is gone.  owever, it's thumbnail remains.  I use this to delete the photo:                                             File fileToDelete = new File(image.filePath);
fileToDelete.delete();                                                                 I then use a managed query to get the thunmbnails for my galleryview control.I've tried to delete the thumbnails, using the same kind of delete code above, with no success.